# Scroll event not working in framework7 - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-framework-7

Am currently using [framework7](https://framework7.io/vue) and I have this problem wherein I need to get a button floating once the user pass scrolling a specific element.

But for some reason am not able to make the scroll event work. Even used a native event listener but still no luck.

Here is my code. In my component:

```
 export default {
    methods: {
    handleScroll(event) {
      alert('should work')
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
    this.handleScroll;
    var element = document.querySelector(".similar-adventures");
    var top = element.offsetTop;
    window.scrollTo(0, top);
  }
}
```

And here is my native event listener code:

```
  window.addEventListener(‘scroll’, function(e){

     // Get the new Value
     newValue = window.pageYOffset;

     //Subtract the two and conclude
     if(oldValue - newValue < 0){
         console.log(“Up”);
     } else if(oldValue - newValue > 0){
         console.log(“Down”);
     }

     // Update the old value
     oldValue = newValue;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old now but i will answer for future reference, so i think the problem here is that the window is not actually scrolling as framework7 uses pages/views.
In vue the  renders to 2 divs like so..

```
<f7-page>
  <div slot="fixed">Fixed element</div>
  <p>Page content goes here</p>
</f7-page>

<!-- Renders to: -->

<div class="page">
  <div>Fixed element</div>
  <div class="page-content">
    <p>Page content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

i found that its the page-content class that you want to put the eventListenter on best way to do this is Dom7 like so...

```
 let page = $$('.page-content')

  page.on('scroll', () => {
    console.log(page.scrollTop()) // will show page top position
    page.scrollTop(0) // will scroll to top
  })

//if you have multiple pages

  let page = $$('.page-content')
  let home = $$(page[0])
  let about = $$(page[1])

  page.on('scroll', () => {
     console.log(home.scrollTop()) //home page top position
     console.log(about.scrollTop()) //about page top position
  })

  //more options 

  page.scrollTop(position, duration, callback)
  page.scrollTo(left, top, duration, callback)
```

just remember to `import $$ from 'Dom7'`

Answer (score 0):

This code retrieves all the pages from the f7 component in an array

```
let pages = document.querySelectorAll('.page-content');
```

Then to make a page scrollable, select the respective index and do:

```
pages[0].addEventListener('scroll', function () { console.log('is scrolling...') } );
```

For the same code but in a more beautiful way as we don't want to specify the page by index:

add an id to your `f7-page` tag

```
  <f7-page name="whatever" id='myPage'>
```

then do this code for example in mounted:

```
let f7page = document.getElementById('myPage');
let scrollableDiv = f7page.querySelector('.page-content');
scrollableDiv.addEventListener('scroll', function () { console.log('is scrolling...') } );
```

*special thanks to BiscuitmanZ's comment for finding the underlying issue*